# How do I create a simple form to table webpage in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple webpage to be run from my work computer. The vast majority of websites are blocked on my work computer, so I was hoping that I could accomplish this task using some simple combination of HTML + CSS + Javascript.

The idea is that the user selects multiple checkboxes for the exams he is interested in, and then he clicks the "Generate Sheet" button which will open a separate tab that displays a table of the break schedules of only the selected exams.

I have already started working on the basics of the code but I keep getting some errors that keep me from moving forward.

Google Chrome's Console debugger gives me the following errors:

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (forAcey.html:59)
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: Checks is not defined
   at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (forAcey.html:33)

The second error shows up when I click the "Generate Sheet" button.

Would you be able to help figure out where my mistakes are and how to correct them?

Additionally, do you have any tips for improving my code in general?

I have attached my code snippet below.

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>Break Schedules</title>
 
 <!-- Style -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="forAcey.css"/> 
 
 <!-- Scripts -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
 <h2>Break Schedules</h2>

 <!-- Form -->
 <div>
  <form id="DateForm">
   <b>Date:</b>
   <input id=DateID type="Date" name="myDate"><br>
  </form>
  
  <h4>Check off the exams you need.</h4>
  
  <div>
   <form id="CheckForm">
    <input type = "checkbox" id="exam1" name="exam1" value="exam1">exam1<br>
    <input type = "checkbox" id="exam2" name="exam2" value="exam2">exam2<br>
    <input type = "checkbox" id="exam3" name="exam3" value="exam3">exam3<br>
   </form> 
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="Checks()">Generate Sheet</button><br>&nbsp<br>
  <button onclick="location.reload()">Reset Form</button>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    Checks();
   return false;
   }
  });
  
  function Checks(){   
  <!-- Date -->
  var x = document.getElementById("DateForm");
  var The_Date = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
   The_Date += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
  }
 }

 var checkexam1=document.getElementById("exam1").checked;
 var checkexam2=document.getElementById("exam2").checked;
 var checkexam3=document.getElementById("exam3").checked;
 
 final_string="<html><h2>"+The_Date+"</h2>
 
 if (exam1==true){
                final_string+="<tr><td>exam1</td><td>this is the break schedule for exam1</td></tr>";
            }
 if (exam2==true){
                final_string+="<tr><td>STEP 1-2-3</td><td>this is the break schedule for exam2</td></tr>";
            }
 if (exam3==true){
                final_string+="<tr><td>PMI</td><td>this is the break schedule for exam3</td></tr>";
            }
 
 final_string+="</table></html>"
            var new_page=window.open('','name');
            new_page.document.write(final_string);
            new_page.document.close();

 
 </script
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quickly, I see that you have multi line string and this is not allowed in javascript (the truth, it's allowed but you have to use backtick and there's compatibility problem with IE).

Comment: How would I write that using backtick?

Comment: «` ...

... `» check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in the script.

- The ending script tag is not closed properly: `</script` should be `</script>`.
- The function Checks should wrap around everything below it, otherwise the part of the script below Checks is executed when the page loads.
- Instead of testing for `exam1 == true`, you need to test for `checkexam1 == true` because that is what your variable is called. Use the strict equality operator to be safe: `checkexam1 === true`.
- There is no beginning `<table>` tag.

Here is the script with corrections:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    Checks();
    return false;
  }
});

function Checks() {
  <!-- Date -->
  var x = document.getElementById("DateForm");
  var The_Date = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    The_Date += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
  }

  var checkexam1 = document.getElementById("exam1").checked;
  var checkexam2 = document.getElementById("exam2").checked;
  var checkexam3 = document.getElementById("exam3").checked;

  var final_string = "<html><h2>" + The_Date + "</h2><table>";

  if (checkexam1 === true) {
    final_string += "<tr><td>exam1</td><td>this is the break schedule for exam1</td></tr>";
  }
  if (checkexam2 === true) {
    final_string += "<tr><td>STEP 1-2-3</td><td>this is the break schedule for exam2</td></tr>";
  }
  if (checkexam3 === true) {
    final_string += "<tr><td>PMI</td><td>this is the break schedule for exam3</td></tr>";
  }

  final_string += "</table></html>";
  var new_page = window.open('', 'name');
  new_page.document.body.innerHTML = final_string;
  new_page.document.close();
}
```

View the working demo: http://plnkr.co/LewFZ4uD4T3SOPNI6iPL

And do not forget to add the missing `>` to the ending script tag!

> Additionally, do you have any tips for improving my code in general?

Since you are using jQuery already, it would be useful to learn how to manipulate the elements directly instead of creating strings of HTML tags. You can learn more at the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/), especially the section on [Manipulating Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/).